# SQL Insert NOT always creating row in table

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, sql-insert

I have a aspx.vb program that checks a table to see if a session exists and if not connects to our ECM software, consumes a license, and updates a table with sessions information. If the user tries to log in again it should find the existing session and still only consume one license.

This works 99% of the time except occasionally a user will consume 2 licenses but only creates one row in the table, which in turn leaves a duplicate session that is caught in limbo and has to be manually disconnected to release the license.

I added logging and its hitting the code as it should and variables are passing correct values. Is it possible the code is running through the logic too fast before the connection can be established with the database?

```
    lvSql = "insert into OnBase_Sessions values (@dbSeqNum,@SID,@UName,@LastActivity,@ccSeqNum)"
            x = New sqlCmds(lvSql, "ONBASEAPI")
            x.addIntParameter("@dbSeqNum", SqlDbType.Int, 4, lvDataSourceSeq)
            x.addStrParameter("@SID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40, lvSession)
            x.addStrParameter("@UName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15, user.userName)
            x.addStrParameter("@LastActivity", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, System.DateTime.Now)
            x.addIntParameter("@ccSeqNum", SqlDbType.Int, 4, lvClientCodeSeq)
            x.exeNonQuery()
```

Comment: Try to update the table first before consuming a license (and of course delete that record if failed to obtain a license). You have not shown us your logic in your aspx page so it's really hard to find out what's going on. If you don't handle your aspx page right, it can do a double postback.

Comment: It looks like your problem is more vast than just the SQL. From what you describe, in some cases the user logs in again, the database hasn't commited the first write so a new license is consumed, and the upon write the database realizes the row is already there. Maybe you need to check if the insertion actually resulted in a new row being created, or in a duplicate error? Or maybe create the session in SQL first, then consume the license?

Comment: It would help if you show how you're checking if a session exists, and how that query is sequenced relative to the insertion statement.

Comment: I am unable to update the table first since I need to connect and consume a license before I can obtain the session information. I think adding a check may be my best bet.

Comment: Update: So I figured out what was happening but don't quite understand why. If two users login in at the same time but for different clients. The slower connection SQL INSERT blends the user params from the user that first hit the application. Example: User 1 SPOT Client code: SP Sessions:12345 and user 2 TSP client code:TP session:6789. USER two is INSERTing TSP, SP, 6789, which is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Learned a valuable lesson on the importance of using Private over Public variable. :p